# VBA Excel Date Dilema , I want to compare today's Year

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare dates(SOP) i have on a sheet to today's YEAR , what i have till know is

```
objDate = CDate("12/31/2016")

For Row = 2 To MAX_Row 
Application.StatusBar = "SOPintheNextYears. Progress: " & Row & " of " & MAX_Row

If (Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row, SOP).Value <= objDate
```

I want `objDate` to be Today's Year , help please .

Comment: `objDate = DateSerial(Year(Now), 12, 31)`.  Note that your Hungarian notation is misleading - dates aren't objects.

Comment: A quick search would give you `Year(Date)` will return the current year.

Answer (score 1):

use VBA [Year()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264675(v=office.15).aspx) function:

```
objDate=year(now)
```